# Where in AWS API Gateway Console is the option to Set up asynchronous invocation of the backend Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Older posts with similar title do not answer the question based on the current (March 2021) AWS API Gateway console.

The AWS docs say "In Integration Request, add an X-Amz-Invocation-Type header with a static value of 'Event'."

But on the API Gateway console after a full hour of looking under rocks I do not see "Integration Request" anywhere?

Comment: Are you using HTTP or REST API?

Comment: currently HTTP but not for any particular reason, does it matter? If easier with REST I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find `"Integration Request"`, because this is  property of only [REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-rest-api.html), not HTTP API.

Specifically, if you want to manage headers for lambda invocations, you have to use [Lambda custom integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html), not the more commonly used [proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html).